# changing my simple html page into mobile friendly

Tags: html

I have this simple html page
http://testphpagain1.comxa.com//index.html

Can you please show how to make it fit/resizes to full screen on any mobile device?

```
<table border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<th></th>
<td>text1</td><td>smile</td></tr>
<tr><th>who are you?</th><td><input type="text" value="0" id="input1" ></td>
<td><input type="text" value="0" id="input2"  ></td></tr>
<tr><th>text2</th><td><input type="text" value="0" id="input3"  ></td><td><input type="text" value="6" id="input4"  ></td></tr><tr><th>age?</th><td><input type="text" value="500" id="input5"  ></td><td><input type="text" value="10" id="input6"  ></td></tr><tr><th>Ratio</th><td><input type="text" value="1243" id="input7"  ></td><td><input type="text" value="100"  id="input8"  ></td></tr><tr><th>what is your name?</th><td><input type="text" value="0" id="input9"  ></td>
<td><input type="text" value="yes" id="input10" "></td>


</tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>test</th><td><input type="text" id="input11"></td><td><input type="text"  id="input12"></td></tr>
<tr><th>test</th><td><input type="text"  id="input13"></td><td><input type="text"  id="input14"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>what??</th></tr>
<tr><th>check this</th><td><input type="text"  id="input15"></td><td><input type="text" id="input16"></td></tr>
<tr><th>nothing here</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>test test test</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>test</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>test</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><th>test</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

**Update**

It is a single page for a single purpose and it won't be part of a website. So no design/graphics are included that I should worry about. The way I want the table to respond is to stay in the middle webpage if it was browsed from PC, but it stretches itself to the boarders of the screen if it was browsed from a mobile or tabled

Comment: To make it resizeable according to screen you can use http://getbootstrap.com/  ..that will help you

Comment: the best and easist way is to use boostrap, which has built-in css classes for tables. Here is a easy beginning http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Comment: I tried the bootstrap, and it stretches fine on phone, but the problem it stretchs on full webpage too. Is there a way of preventing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a table with no widths set, it's already exhibiting responsive traits (nothing overhangs, it all just squashes to fit the screen already).

Maybe you need to be more specific about HOW you want it to respond?

Also, I would recommend that you not overdo it on the tables (unless your designing a HTML email). It's quite an ugly and old fashioned way to design websites.

If you get a better idea on how you want it to respond, I would recommend media queries! Simple to use, and work well on almost all devices and browsers (and who cares about responsiveness on really old browsers like IE8 anyway?)

They are done in the following way (just an example):

```
@media all and (max-width:1024px){
    table{
        font-size:12px;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a single page for a single purpose and it won't be part of a website. So no design/graphics are included that I should worry about. The way I want the table to respond is to stay in the middle webpage if it was browsed from PC, but it stretches itself to the boarders of the screen if it was browsed from a mobile or tabled

Comment: Thanks, worked very well for me. I guess I wasn't use to using CSS, and it seems I should be learning it if I want to do something for both PC and Phones/Tablets

Comment: Indeed sir - no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here how to go along

```
<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table-bordered"><tbody><tr><th></th>...</table></div>
```